# Form-invariant solution to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to understand how to create form-invariant solutions to PDEs.

> Let  $u(x,t): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, which solves the differential equation $\hat{L}u(x,t)=0$.
>
> $u(x,t)$ is *form-invariant*, iff $|u\big(x,t\big)|^2=|u\big(f(t)\cdot x + g(t),0\big)|^2$.

During evolution, the abolute-square of $u$ does not change, except of dilatation $f(t)$ and translation $g(t)$.

**Example**: An example of such solutions are (higher-order) [gaussian solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) for the paraxial wave equation.

I tried

- $u(x,t)=A(x,t)\cdot \exp(i\cdot h(x,t))$, with $A,h: (x,t) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the simple 1-dimensional cases of the paraxial wave equation
- $u(x,t)=u(f(t)\cdot x,0)$, $u: (x,t) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the 1-dimensional heat-equation

but arrived at PDEs which I was unable to solve.

**Questions**

1. Is there a general method/idea for creating form-invariant solutions?
2. Is it known whether form-invariant solutions exist for many PDEs?
3. Can you provide literature to this topic (google is not helping this time)?
4. Can you make suggestions such that my question is better understandable and receive more attention?

Comment: 4. You could add a precise definition of "form-invariant solution" to your question. This might help in clarifying

Comment: Thanks Guiseppe, I tried to clarify what I mean. Is it more useful now? Do you have any further suggestions for clarification?